# How do you set precision of decimal when there is an "E" involved within the number?

Tags: php, rounding

I want to trim my decimal into something like `8.063` instead of the original which is `8.0638304611694E-9`. I have implemented a function for it but it doesn't work when there is `E-9` in it. Which part should I modify??

```php
public function setPrecision($number, $decimals = 0)
{
    $negation = ($number < 0) ? (-1) : 1;
    $coefficient = 10 ** $decimals;
    return $negation * floor((string)(abs($number) * $coefficient)) / $coefficient;
}
```

**EDIT**

The current implementation gave me `0` when I try to call the function.

```php
setPrecision(8.0638304611694E-9, 3); // 0
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php ? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php ? If not then please make clear why they wouldn't work for you.

Comment: number format doesn't seem to work properly with my numbers, and it also gave me 0.000. I'll update my question

Comment: In reality something like `8.0638304611694E-9` is `0.0000000080638304611694`.

Comment: The result in your function call (edit) seems correct to me? You're rounding down, and like KIKO Software said your number is close to 0 in the 3rd decimal.

Comment: I tried to use 12 as my `$decimals` parameter of the function, it works, but somehow it kept the `E-9` on the result. I want to completely remove it

Comment: Ok I think the issue is maybe just the tiny value of the number. When you try to round to 3 decimal places, it simply rounds it out of existence - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e118f865f804261dc67ee43441b1a8741a78fa1. The E is a red herring - that's just a presentation format (as KIKO Software has effectively pointed out already).

Comment: @Tamma You could use number_format() for that. It returns a string though so you'd have to convert it back to a float.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo no, same issue it turns out. See my demo in the comment above.

Comment: Your current implementation also produces `123.45` from `setPrecision(123.4567, 2)`. Do you need `1.23`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález surely that would change the value, rather than simply altering the precision

Comment: @ADyson He's asking just that for tiny numbers, thus my question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález ah I see what you mean. I think though, from reading the question and the comments that maybe the OP hasn't quite understood the presentation format involving the E. I guess that's what you're hinting at?

Comment: @ADyson Yes? I don't see what's wrong with the rounding in your demo? It's just a case of calculating the number of decimals correctly.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález is right, I'm confused by the E in the number and how to format it properly. I just want to get rid of that `E-9` and print only the number, with 3 decimal points ofc.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo yes but you said "you could use number_format for that". By "that" I assumed, you meant the result the OP stated they wanted. But number_format doesn't produce what the OP wants (partly because it doesn't actually make a lot of sense)

Comment: @ADyson It's getting too abstract here. number_format() can format the scientific notation value as an "ordinary float". Period. On the other hand it's totally possible that this might not be what OP wants. I'm not sure if OP understands the different notations or if that can be expressed in comment texts though.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo no I don't think they do. That's the nub of the issue, it turns out. See also comments on the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, there are (at the moment of writing) [8519 builtin functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/indexes.functions.php). One of them probably does the trick!

You could use `log10()` and `round()` in your function:

```php
function setPrecision($number, $precision = 0)
{
    $exponent = floor(log10($number)) - 1;
    return round($number, -$exponent + $precision - 1);
}
```

Comment: Note: the function could be optimized, but it is supposed to be readable.

Comment: This will output 8.064E-9, which isn't quite what the OP is looking for (although closer than anything else so far, admittedly)

Comment: I tried it, as @ADyson pointed, it still printing the `E-9` in the number. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: @Tamma why exactly do you need/want to get rid of it? It's just a presentation format. The underlying number it represents is still the same. It's not something you need to worry about until you're trying to present the number to a human, really. A function to change the precision is a mathematical operation, not a presentation operation. As has been pointed out above, if you simply remove `E-9` from `8.063E-9` then you get `8.063` which is not the same number!

Comment: @ADyson , the end result requires me to print just 8.063 without the E-9 in the UI

Comment: @Tamma but that would be misleading for the reader, because `8.063` is `8.063`, whereas `8.063E-9` is actually `0.000000008063`. Not the same thing. The `E...` format just provides a more compact way to write it down. If you round `0.000000008063` to 3 decimal places using conventional rounding, you get `0.000`, as I've already demonstrated. https://www.calculator.net/scientific-notation-calculator.html?cvtnum=8.063E-9&ctype=1&submit1=Convert

Comment: @ADyson , Yes, I get your point. I think that is fine since this was a homework for my study in university, not a very critical project that needs the accurate result. The lecturer just told me to do it. If there is solution for it, I'll be very happy.

Comment: @Tamma there really isn't a solution because it doesn't make sense. Are you _sure_ that's what your lecturer told you to do? If so, they need a mathematics lesson.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239909/discussion-between-tamma-and-adyson).

Answer (score 0):

Relative rounding with a certain number of digits can easily be done with sprintf.

```
$round = (float)sprintf('%0.3E', 8.0638304611694E-9);
var_dump($round);  //float(8.064E-9)
```

On this basis I have this function which rounds float values with a certain relative decimal precision.

```
 /*
  * @return Float-Value with reduced precision
  * @param $floatValue: input (float)
  * @param $overallPrecision: 1..20 (default 10)
  */
  function roundPrecision($floatValue, $overallPrecision = 10)
  {
    $p = min(20,max(0,$overallPrecision-1));
    $f =(float)sprintf('%.'.$p.'e',$floatValue);
    return $f;
  }
```

example 1

```
  $float = 0.0000123456789;
  $newFloat = roundPrecision($float,5);
  printf('%0.10f',$newFloat);  //0.0000123460
```

example 2

```
  $float = 3456.7891234;
  $newFloat = roundPrecision($float,5);
  printf('%0.10f',$newFloat);  //3456.8000000000
```

Comment: Have you read any of the comments and discussion?